# Is it possible to use CloudPages for blogging?

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

Is it possible to use CloudPages for blogging in place of a tool like WordPress? We want to migrate a WordPress.com blog to our website, and the ability to capture contact interactions seems worth the effort of building pages within Content Builder for our on-site blog. Does anyone have experience with this? What are some of the pros and cons of doing so?

Comment: One big con is that CloudPages charge per view, so it can become very expensive very quickly, especially as your audience grows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically you can do so and store your articles in Data Extensions and serve them from there, but the functionality isn't designed to do so and the implementation would require a lot of work.

Keep in mind that CloudPages views are consuming SuperMessages - for more information on that contact your AccountExecutive.

If you just like to capture web interactions/views, you could do so by implementing the CollectCode on your current blog and pass your contact's identifyer to the website as a parameter. If you are talking about fields capturing information, submitting to a CloudPage but hosting the rest of the blog elsewhere seems like a better fit.